# unincorn + rails ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my rails app to digitalocean with postgresql database .
my database.yml looks like this

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: rails
  password: 

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myorganicmantra_production
  username: rails
  password:
```

i did rake db:create and it shows myorganicmantra_production already exists
but when i am restarting unicorn server and loking to unicorn.log there is line like ]

```
ERROR -- : FATAL:  database "myorganicmantra_production" does not exist
 (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)
```

and eventually it is shwing 504 timeout on the webpage

here is my /etc/default/unicorn file

```
APP_ROOT=/home/rails/myorganicmantra

# Server's config.rb, it's not a rack's config.ru
CONFIG_RB=/etc/unicorn.conf

# Where to store PID, sh'ld be also set in server's config.rb, option "pid".
PID=/var/run/unicorn.pid
RAILS_ENV="production"
UNICORN_OPTS="-D -c $CONFIG_RB -E $RAILS_ENV"

PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/unicorn

# Generate by running `rake -f /home/rails/rails_project/Rakefile secret`
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=7a4a64cb96134c5fc9b621c6c475740fb119286282ef9bdfb7d858c53c3eac7d8496412be3f43415cf98e568c65d851422baef810ac87bd28d52eef8cb49c235
export APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=OREXemjvCj
```

Comment: try $ bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: already did RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 0):

what is the environment your application is running in the unicorn mode. If you starting unicorn by using a command as follows then, check what is passed as part of the -E parameter

```
bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production
```

If it is not production then, probably your application is running in development mode.

Comment: added my unicorn file @Pragash there -E is production